# Sort Based on the Result of a Subtraction Operation

Tags: c++, vector, 3d

My actual case is that I have a `vector<Point3D>` where `Point3D` is a class I defined. The `Point3D` less than operator defines a `Point3D` to be smaller if it's closer to the origin. The addition operator is defined to allow `Point3D`s to be shifted by another `Point3D`. What I want to do is:

**Find what will be the minimum element of the `vector` as defined `Point3D`'s less than operator after adding a `POINT3D` to every element in the `vector`**

Now I'd like to do this without actually modifying the `vector`. I'd be awesome if the standard provided me something like `min_element` that did this for me.

---

To simplify the question, here's what I'd like to see:

## Given a `vector<int>` find the element that would be the minimum if all elements were multiplied by -1. Ideally using only one standard function.

This can be solved by doing `max_element` that will *not* solve my actual problem and will be no help to me.

For a test example, given: `vector<int>{1, 3, 4, 2}` the correct solution would provide a pointer or index to the third element (4). Is there a simple way to solve this or do I need to write my own loop iterating through all the elements and holding onto a pointer to the min?

Comment: You could write your own comparison function, is there anything that stops you from doing that? Or, if C++11 is an option, a quick lambda would also suffice.

Comment: `std::max_element` or `std::min_element` using your own comparator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the point in question to each point that is sent to the comparison function for `max_element`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
//...
Point3D somePt;
std::vector<Point3D> vectPts;
//...
//... assume that somePt has a value you want to add and vectPts is the vector
//    of points to get the minimum of
//...
auto smallestPtIter = std::max_element(vectPts.begin(), vectPts.end() [&] 
(const Point3D& p1, const Point3D& p2) { return p1 + somePt < p2 + somePt; });
```

If you're using a version of C++ prior to 11, the following can be done:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
//...
struct functor
{
   Point3D adder;
   functor(const Point3D& a) : adder(a) {}
   bool operator()(const Point3D& p1, const Point3D& p2) 
   { return p1 + adder < p2 + adder; }
};

void foo() 
{
    Point3D somePt;
    std::vector<Point3D> vectPts;
    //...
    //... assume that somePt has a value you want to add and vectPts is the vector
    //    of points to get the minimum of
    //...
    functor f(somePt);
    std::vector<Point3D>::iterator smallestPtIter = std::max_element(vectPts.begin(), vectPts.end(), f);
//...
}
```

Comment: Very nice, sadly I'm without C++11. I guess I can make a global and still accomplish this with my own function.

Answer (score 0):

You simply walk through your sequence maintaining a pointer/iterator to the smallest value seen so far. You can pass a function object comp that takes two arguments and returns true if the first is less than the second.

```
using iterator = std::vector<int>::iterator;
iterator smallest(iterator begin, iterator end, 
                  std::function<bool(int, int)> comp) {
  auto min_ptr = begin;
  for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
    if (comp(*begin, *smallest)) smallest = begin;
  }
  return smallest;
}
```

Now we call smallest using whatever function you want to use to compare two integers. A lambda expression is convenient. But you could use a function pointer or a function object as well since they will all bind to the std::function parameter.

```
vector<int> my_vector {1, 4, 6, 3};
auto min_ptr = smallest(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), 
    [](int i, int j) { return -1 * i < -1 * j; });
```

Comment: The above answer using std::min_element is better.